# Changing the source column for a list of functions

Tags: excel

I have a column of functions that each pull from a specific column across several sheets. The column has shifted in these source sheets so that the function pulling is pulling from Column E when it should be pulling from Column D. Is there a quick way to update all these functions so that they pull from the correct column from the source sheets.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Copy and Replace function (Ctrl+H) but you're going to need to be extremely careful. The idea is that you can use a common element in the formulas that you need to change. For example, if your cells contain the formula `=E2`, `=E3`, etc., you can type `=E` in 'Find What' and `=D` in 'Replace With'. Be careful, though, since this will find *anything* that contains `=E` and change it.

Make backups of your backups before you try this.

Comment: Excellent it seems to have worked. Thanks again for your help.